# dplyr broadcasting single value per group in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do something very similar to [Scale relative to a value in each group (via dplyr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117429/scale-relative-to-a-value-in-each-group-via-dplyr) (however this solution seems to crash R for me). I would like to replicate a single value for each group and add a new column with this value repeated. As an example I have

```
library(dplyr)

data = expand.grid(
  category = LETTERS[1:2],
  year = 2000:2003)
data$value = runif(nrow(data))

data

  category year     value
1        A 2000 0.6278798
2        B 2000 0.6112281
3        A 2001 0.2170495
4        B 2001 0.6454874
5        A 2002 0.9234604
6        B 2002 0.9311204
7        A 2003 0.5387899
8        B 2003 0.5573527
```

And I would like a dataframe like

```
data

  category year     value    value2
1        A 2000 0.6278798 0.6278798
2        B 2000 0.6112281 0.6112281
3        A 2001 0.2170495 0.6278798
4        B 2001 0.6454874 0.6112281
5        A 2002 0.9234604 0.6278798
6        B 2002 0.9311204 0.6112281
7        A 2003 0.5387899 0.6278798
8        B 2003 0.5573527 0.6112281
```

i.e. the value for each category is the value from year 2000. I was trying to think of a general solution extensible to a given filtering criteria, i.e. something like

```
data %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(value = filter(data, year==2002))
```

however this does not work because of incorrect length in the assignment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do this:

```
data %>% group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value2 = value[year == 2000])
```

You could also do it this way:

```
data %>% group_by(category) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(value2 = value[1])
```

or

```
data %>% group_by(category) %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(value2 = first(value))
```

or

```
data %>% group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value2 = nth(value, n = 1, order_by = "year"))
```

or probably several other ways.

Your attempt with `mutate(value = filter(data, year==2002))` doesn't make sense for a few reasons.

1. When you explicitly pass in `data` again, it's not part of the chain that got grouped earlier, so it doesn't know about the grouping.
2. All `dplyr` verbs take a data frame as first argument and return a data frame, including `filter`. When you do `value = filter(...)` you're trying to assign a full data frame to the single column `value`.

Comment: ahh okay, yes I knew there was something fishy about passing in data into filter() again but could not think of a way to do this otherwise. In your first example am I correct in assuming under the hood something of the form data[data$year==2002,] is happening and then since this is within the context of a group it is aware how to broadcast these values?

Comment: When things are grouped, think of it like you have an individual data frame for each group, so it's starting with `sub_df = data[data$category == "A"]`. From there, `dplyr` knows the column names, so `value[year == 2000]` it knows to look inside `sub_df`  for `year == 2000`, which will returns a boolean vector, TRUE for the rows when year is 2000. It subsets `value`, which is a corresponding vector of `value` based on the boolean vector we created with `year == 2000`.

Comment: Data table does this more explicitly, referring to the sub-data-frames by `.SD` (stands for **s**ub **d**ata table).